# Is there a way to trigger the page navigation when a specific variable in provider class changes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

is there a way to trigger the page navigation when a specific variable in provider class changes?
for example.
I want to navigate to login screen whenever the `appLock` variable becomes true otherwise do nothing

```
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppLockHelper()),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<AppLockHelper>().startThread();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      ),
      supportedLocales: L10n.all,
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my provider class

```
 class AppLockHelper extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _appLocked = false;
  bool get appLocked => _appLocked;
  final _get = GenericGetApi();
  Timer? timer;
  void startThread() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => getAppStatus());
  }

  void stopThread() {
    timer?.cancel();
  }

  Future<void> getAppStatus() async {
    var appStatusResult =
        await _get.get(endpoint: EndPointsPool.getAppLockStatus);
    appStatusResult.fold((l) {
      _appLocked = false;
    }, (r) {
      AppLock appLockResult = AppLock.fromJson(r);
      _appLocked = appLockResult.applocked;
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the solution would be add a listner in initState.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final myNotifier = context.read<AppLockHelper>();
    void listener() {
      myNotifier.appLocked
          ? Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/log-in", (_) => false)
          : null;
    }

    myNotifier.addListener(listener);
  }
```